# I have installed SDL but it still doesn't seem to work

Tags: c, sdl

I am on a mac.
So I've looked everywhere what i first did was download the SDL file from `https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL`
After that i followed the instructions on `https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation`
and wrote the following on my terminal

```
mkdir build
cd build
../configure
make
sudo make install
```

so far so good but after this when i cd to my Desktop and type  `gcc test.c sdl2-config --cflags --libs` into my terminal it still gives me the error

```
test.c:2:10: fatal error: 'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

if i type just `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` into my terminal it returns

```
-I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -D_THREAD_SAFE
-L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2
```

so i think it is successfully installed any idea on what the problem is?
Thanks a lot

Comment: What happens if you add `-I/usr/local/include` (to the gcc command)?

Comment: it seems to have worked,could you please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your header is located at `/usr/local/include/SDL2/SDL.h` but you're trying to include `/usr/local/include/SDL2/SDL2/SDL.h`. Either remove "SDL2" from your `#include` statement or your `-I` switch.

Comment: /usr/include/SDL2 should *already* be on the include path, or something is weird.